# Is it possible to create a pair of polarized, polarization-entangled photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-entanglement, polarization

Is there a light source which emits (mostly) polarization-entangled pairs of photons that have a known polarization angle, e.g. a certain angle in relation to the orientation of the source?

Applying filters to pairs of photons with unknown polarization won't do it, because it would break entanglement.

Comment: Polarization entanglement means that neither photon has a definite polarization in any direction.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So my question did not make sense.

Comment: Siyuan Shi et al. [Generation of photonic entanglement in green fluorescent proteins, Nature Communications](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-02027-9) (2017). DOI: 10.1038/s41467-017-02027-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about sources that emit polarization-entangled photon pairs, but polarization-entangled pairs can be obtained from a polarized source in many ways.

One example is Spontaneous Parametric Down Conversion ([SPDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion)). Quoting from Wikipedia:

> In a commonly used SPDC apparatus design, a strong laser beam, termed the "pump" beam, is directed at a BBO (beta-barium borate) crystal. Most of the photons continue straight through the crystal. However, occasionally, some of the photons undergo spontaneous down-conversion with Type II polarization correlation, and the resultant correlated photon pairs have trajectories that are constrained to be within two cones, whose axes are symmetrically arranged relative to the pump beam. Also, due to the conservation of energy, the two photons are always symmetrically located within the cones, relative to the pump beam. **Importantly, the trajectories of the photon pairs may exist simultaneously in the two lines where the cones intersect. This results in entanglement of the photon pairs whose polarization are perpendicular**.

[image]

If $\mid V \rangle$ denotes a vertically polarized photon and $\mid H \rangle$ a horizontally polarized photon, then at the intersection of the two cones it will be possible to find photons in the state

$$\mid \psi \rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} (\mid H \rangle \mid V \rangle +  \mid V \rangle \mid H \rangle)$$

(See [here](http://pdxscholar.library.pdx.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1088&context=honorstheses) for more details)

Notice anyway that, as Mark Mitchison pointed out, in an entangled pair neither photon has a definite polarization. To understand why, consider the state

$$\mid \phi \rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} (\mid H \rangle \mid V \rangle +  \mid V \rangle \mid V \rangle)$$

This state is not entangled, as it can be written as

$$\mid \phi \rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} (\mid H \rangle+  \mid V \rangle ) \mid V \rangle$$

So we know that in this state one photon has vertical polarization, while the other is polarized at $45°$. You can easily see that the same trick cannot be applied to the entangled $\mid \psi \rangle$ state: an entangled state is in fact, by definition, *non separable*.

So even if you know the polarization state of the two photons before the entanglement, the creation of the entanglement itself will destroy any information about the individual polarization of the photons.

Comment: As the equation says, after entangling the two photons no longer have a definite polarization angle. This conforms to Mark Mitchisons comment above.

Comment: I misinterpreted your question, then. Yes, you cannot have entanglement and a definite polarization at the same time.

Comment: Does this mean that two existing polarized photons with a relative polarization angle of 0° can never get polarization-entangled, or that they will lose their polarization when becoming entangled?

Comment: Yes, basically. It is possible to think of a sequence of optical elements that transform the state you described ($\mid HH \rangle$ or $\mid VV\rangle$, basically) in an entangled state, but when the entanglement is created you will lose the information about the polarization of the individual photon.

Comment: I will update my answer to include these remarks.